# how to be notified when a greenlet is scheduled to run and when it yields

Tags: python, asynchronous, gevent, greenlets

Is there a way (even a hack) with which I can be notified when a eventloop (gevent) selects a greenlet to run.
I want to be able to profile the time taken by my greenlets, each time they run and yield. 
I can call a callback from within my method, but there are multiple entry points and exit points and the code is complicated. So I am looking for something from the selectors.